# Any service for testing Android applications on multiple Hardware devices?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-build

I have developed a android application which I want to test on multiple devices
 before I release in market. Is there any service provider online who will test the
 application on as many android devices as possible and give me the test results 
like the performance, bugs etc. Any kind of helpful details in this regards is 
appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.perfectomobile.com/portal/cms/Services/android

Comment: Hi @fermi ... Let me ask you something, those seem to be more AUTOMATED services.  (Eg with LessPainful.com you use calabash or something to remotely get screenshots etc.) I've really been struggling to find essentially a "manual" testing house. You send them a build and they test it on 50 devices manually and you talk to them etc.  As an Android dev, you may know something like this? A totally mystery to me in iOS-land as I don't know the Android business scene!!!!  Thanks in advance if you see this note,

Comment: You're unfortunately don't have a ton of choices: I've looked at (but not used) folks like TestDroid (http://testdroid.com/), Testology (http://www.testology.co.uk/) and utest (http://www.utest.com/). Depending on your release volume and number of apps you may want to invest a couple of thousand in your own suite of test devices.

Comment: thanks a million Fermi it helps - in fact I too found Testology in the UK and Andy is great. They have about 40 Android 4+ devices.  We now use them constantly, they are pretty much a must for any serious Android dev.  Testdroid and so on are only automated so of little value for games and smoke testing, i found. You really need a manual service with a pile of devices. Thanks again really.