# How to test when new version releases for android

Tags: android, android-version

I don't have facility to buy each phone with new version release for android. Means if android had release 5.0 then how can I test whether my application will work or not. Please specify any strategy possible for this without buying a phone.

Comment: you can emulators for different devices and versions

Answer (score 0):

There are a plenty of online services to provide testing on real devices remotely. For example, http://www.perfectomobile.com/

Please use search before posting duplicated questions: [Any service for testing Android applications on multiple Hardware devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352748/any-service-for-testing-android-applications-on-multiple-hardware-devices)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a new android version will be released, the `SDK Platform` for the new version will be available for download, so you can download it and create an emulator for that version.

So you will be able to test your application on any release.